# One ESP8266 not letting other ESP8266 stay on network

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I have 2 ESP8266's that I wanna connect to a same network with different static addresses. One works perfectly. When I add another, both stop working. After reading more about here https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/issues/259, I'm thinking it's an issue with client ID, but I don't know how to solve it. This is the code I'm using:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "ESP Test";
const char* password = "88888888";

; // 
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
IPAddress ip(192,168,5,199); 
IPAddress gateway(192,168,5,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);   
WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");

}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }

  // Read the first line of the request
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.flush();

  // Match the request


  if (request.indexOf("/light1on") > 0)  {
    digitalWrite(0, HIGH);

  }
  if (request.indexOf("/light1off") >0)  {
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);

  }

   if (request.indexOf("/light2on") > 0)  {
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);

  }
  if (request.indexOf("/light2off") >0)  {
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);

  }
    if (request.indexOf("/light3on") >0)  {
    digitalWrite(0, HIGH);

  }
  if (request.indexOf("/light3off") > 0)  {
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);

  }
   if (request.indexOf("/light4on") > 0)  {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

  }
  if (request.indexOf("/light4off") > 0)  {
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);

  }
// Set ledPin according to the request
//digitalWrite(ledPin, value);

  // Return the response
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
  client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
  client.println("<html>");
  client.println("<head>");
  client.println("<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes' />");
  client.println("<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style' content='black-translucent' />");
 client.println("</head>");
  client.println("<body bgcolor = \"#f7e6ec\">"); 
  client.println("<hr/><hr>");
  client.println("<h4><center> Esp8266 Electrical Device Control </center></h4>");
  client.println("<hr/><hr>");
  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("<center>");
  client.println("Device 1");
  client.println("<a href=\"/light1on\"\"><button>Turn On </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/light1off\"\"><button>Turn Off </button></a><br />");  
  client.println("</center>");   
  client.println("<br><br>");
   client.println("<center>");
   client.println("Device 2");
  client.println("<a href=\"/light2on\"\"><button>Turn On </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/light2off\"\"><button>Turn Off </button></a><br />");  
client.println("</center>"); 
  client.println("<br><br>");
    client.println("<center>");
   client.println("Device 3");
  client.println("<a href=\"/light3on\"\"><button>Turn On </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/light3off\"\"><button>Turn Off </button></a><br />");  
client.println("</center>"); 
  client.println("<br><br>");
   client.println("<center>");
   client.println("Device 4");
  client.println("<a href=\"/light4on\"\"><button>Turn On </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/light4off\"\"><button>Turn Off </button></a><br />");  
client.println("</center>"); 
  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("<center>");
  client.println("<table border=\"5\">");
 client.println("<tr>");
  if (digitalRead(5))
         { 
           client.print("<td>Light 1 is ON</td>");
                 }
          else
          {
            client.print("<td>Light 1 is OFF</td>");
              }

        client.println("<br />");

         if (digitalRead(4))
          { 
           client.print("<td>Light 2 is ON</td>");

         }
          else
          {
            client.print("<td>Light 2 is OFF</td>");
          }
          client.println("</tr>");
          client.println("<tr>");
          if (digitalRead(0))
          { 
           client.print("<td>Light 3 is ON</td>");
          }

          else
          {
            client.print("<td>Light 3 is OFF</td>");
          }
          if (digitalRead(13))
          { 
           client.print("<td>Light 4 is ON</td>");

          }
          else
          {
            client.print("<td>Light 4 is OFF</td>");
         }

          client.println("</tr>");


          client.println("</table>");

          client.println("</center>");
  client.println("</html>"); 
  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Client disonnected");
  Serial.println("");

}
```

Comment: What UART controllers did you hook the ESP8266s to? Are you using SoftwareSerial?

Comment: I don't know what that is, neither UARD nor SoftwareSerial. I'm using ESP8266 and few led diodes.

Comment: The ESP8266 TX and RX should be connected to a [UART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver-transmitter) on the Arduino. What pins did you connect the TX and RX of the ESP8266 on the Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't add a comment, I'll post this as an answer.
Please be aware that this is mostly speculation

I just wonder if there is an issue with mac addresses?
Have you checked both devices to ensure that they have unique mac addresses?

If they have identical addresses, this may be the issue.
[If found this article](https://yoursunny.com/t/2017/change-ESP8266-MAC/) which may help. I've not tried it but the author shows how to change the mac address on an esp8266 device.

As I say, speculation :)